# Preg_match, if <code></code> formatted correctly

Tags: php, preg-match

```
if(preg_match("/(.*(&lt;code&gt;).*(&lt;\/code&gt;).*)*/", $string))
```

I was trying many hours already, but I can't make it work. I want that if user formatted text correctly like:

```
(any_string*<code>any_string*</code>any_string*)*
```

Only then I would format text with * meaning empty string or many times. What's wrong with my expression?

**edit:** I want to match `lalala text <code>dlalala lala code</code> lalalal`. If it's `lala <code> lalala` or `lalal </code> <code> lalala <code>alala` then we don't want to match it.

Comment: Your regex isn't incorrect at all. However, are you trying to match multiple-line content between the tags? Then remember the dot matches anything BUT newlines.

Comment: Can you post some examples of the string that you want to match?

Comment: It is not correct, it makes it always true.

Comment: Does any_string* has to be the same in front, middle and after the code tags?

Comment: I think the reason it is always true is that the entire thing is contained within a subpattern with an asterisk after it, which means the entire pattern can match zero times and still be considered a match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works with the 2 given test cases:

```
$arr = array('lalala text <code>dlalala lala code</code> lalalal.',
             'lala <code> lalala or lalal </code> <code> lalala <code>alala');
foreach ($arr as $str) {
    echo "$str\n";
    if (preg_match('#^(?<!<code>).*<code>.*?</code>(?!.*<code>)#', $str)) {
        echo "===> Match\n";
    } else {
        echo "===> Not match\n";
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
lalala text <code>dlalala lala code</code> lalalal.
===> Match
lala <code> lalala or lalal </code> <code> lalala <code>alala
===> Not match
```

Some explanation about the regex:

```
#           : regex delimiter
^           : begining of string
  (?<!      : start negative lookbehind
    <code>  : literally <code>
  )         : end of lookbehind
  .*        : any char any number of time
  <code>    : literally <code>
  .*?       : any char any number of time not greedy
  </code>   : literally </code>
  (?!       : start negative lookahead
    .*      : any char any number of time
    <code>  : literally <code>
  )         : end of lookahead
#           : regex delimiter
```

You can find some usefull informations about lookaround [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: It seems to work. Can you describe how it works just a little bit?

Answer (score 4):

You probably could use greed killer `?` in your code expression (more info here: [Matching text between delimiters: greedy or lazy regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227664/matching-text-between-delimiters-greedy-or-lazy-regular-expression) ), so if you have a code like this:

```
<code>foo</code> another <code>bar</code>
```

It will match just `foo` and `bar` not `foo</code> another <code>bar`, also you should use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) (with flag `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`) and write your own parser. Or rather use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) like this:

```
// Just strtolower example (this would do formatting)
function myCallback( $matches){
    return strlower( $matches[2]);
}

$string = preg_replace_callback("/(&lt;code&gt;).*?(&lt;\/code&gt;)/si", 'myCallback', $string)
```

Note the question-mark in `.*?`. You also should use `s` and `i` modifiers so your code would work on codes like this:

```
lorem ipsum <code>
foo
</code> bar
```

If you need validation you can use this:

```
$string = preg_replace("/(&lt;code&gt;).*?(&lt;\/code&gt;)/si", '', $string);
if( (strpos( $string, '<code') !== false) || (strpos( $string, '</code') !== false){
    echo 'Invalid code';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$string = "aaa<code>asd</code>aaaasd";
if (preg_match("#[a-zA-Z ]+<code>[a-zA-Z ]+<\/code>[a-zA-Z ]+#", $string))
{
echo "It's a match!\n";
} else {
echo "No match, sorry.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $string = "aaa<code>dlalala lala code</code>aaa";
    if (preg_match("#.*<code>.*<\/code>.*#", $string)) {
            echo "OK\n";
    } else {
            echo "NOK\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try these

```
$string = "lalala text <code>dlalala lala code</code> lalalal";

if(strlen($string)>0){
    preg_match("/\<code\>(.*)\<\/code\>/",$string, $code);
    echo $code[1];
}else{
    echo "no code found";
}
```

output will be:

> dlalala lala code

Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$sample_text = <<<EOF
blah blah
<code>one</code>
foo<code>two</code>three</code>
<code><code>four</code>bar
</code><code>five</code>foobar
<code>six</code>
blah blah blah
EOF;

preg_match_all('/<code>(?\'code\'((?!<\/?code>).)*)<\/code>/', $sample_text, $codes);

print_r($codes); 
?>
```

i believe is what you're looking for.  i referred to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) and tested the regex [here](http://regexpal.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using strpos for simple string comparisons like this, which means you don't have to worry about escaping special characters, and it's faster.

This will work

***EDITED TO GET POSTION OF TAGS.***

```
$string = "This string has 'Anything <code> anything </code> anything' in it in the right order.";
$start = strpos($string, '<code>');
$end = strpos($string, '</code>');
if ($start !== FALSE && $end !== FALSE && $end > $start){
     echo $string;
}else{
    echo 'incorrectly formatted';
}
```

**IF YOU WANT TO USE PREG_MATCH**

```
if(preg_match("/.*(<code>).*(<\/code>).*/", $string)){
       echo $string
  }
```

Note - you don't want to use HTML entities unless you are sure the string is formatted using HTML entities. You don't need the outer set of parentheses.

Comment: If this answer does not do what you want, can you tell me why and in what way?

Comment: You may have reasons for preferring preg_match, but your comment takes me back to strpos. Strpos makes sure that there isn't a </code> in front of a <code> because it stops checking after the first match. Otherwise I'd refer you to the first answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags and suggest an xml parser. In other words - regex sucks at validating HTML and is best avoided.

Comment: Final answer - try http://querypath.org/ I've never used it, but it looks a much better way to handle HTML input and get rid of the garbage.